# insalata, vegetale e insalata, piatto

Tags: etymology, homograph

In Italiano una classe di vegetali a foglia, commestibili, viene denominata insalata, cosí come viene denominata insalata una classe di piatti in cui spesso, ma non necessariamente (insalata russa, insalata di frutta) vengono usati i vegetali a foglia di cui sopra.

Ho tre ipotesi da sottoporre al vostro giudizio:

- l'insalata, verdura, prende il nome dal piatto, insalata, dove spessissimo figura;
- l'insalata, piatto, prende il nome dall'insalata, verdura, che spessissimo entra nella sua composizione;
- entrambe le accezioni hanno un antenato comune, da cui entrambe derivano, cosí come l'uomo non discende dalla scimmia, ma scimmie e uomini discendono da un'antichissima progenitrice.